# List items won't appear next to eachother

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I have a problem and I can't seem to find the solution.

I'm making a drupal site, and I want to make these list-items come next to eachother. Their width is 45% so it should be possible to have 2 next to eachother, but I can't figure out how.

[image]

I've tried putting display inline and inline-block on mutiple of the UL's and LI's but nothing changes.

What should I do?

Comment: If you can post the code instead of the image, we can find the solution.

Comment: Share your html and css code or create a fiddle so that we can inspect the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use float :

```css
ul {
  width: 940px;
}
li {
  margin: 6px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/450/200/2" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/450/200/2" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/450/200/2" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/450/200/2" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find out what you are doing wrong when you don't provide any code.

My guess is that you have not changed the display type and thus the elements are still blocks. If so then it does not matter how the width is set, each element will stay on it's own row.

either use `float` or `display:inline;` if you want to show the list items next to each other

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f19tnw0k/) for an example of different methods and why some don't work.